# Why does searching for "Stream" in Windows return every file?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1

If I open Windows Explorer and go to my Desktop (or whatever) and search (file contents, not just titles) in the top right search box for `stream` I have every file returned. If I pick a file, open it in a text editor and search for `stream` I get no hits.

What is special about this? I have images returned too. In there some piece of meta data I'm not seeing but Windows is?

Update:

I created an empty file and looked at it in a hex editor to confirm it is empty.

[image: Empty file in hex editor]

This file show sup when I search for `stream`. it is 0 KB.

Update2:

I checked at home on Windows 8.1 and it happens there too.

I think this is some Windows "feature" I am not understanding.

Comment: Yes;  Windows is picking up some sort of metadata.

Comment: Where is this? What is it? Why does every file have it? How can I view these data?

Comment: You won't see it unless you use a hex editor

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think that's the case. I opened it in a hex editor and it revealed nothing extra. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

This is a (good) guess, but I'm reasonably sure you are seeing evidence of something called "alternate data streams", which is an NTFS feature that permits the storage "in" a file of alternate data that is only retrieved with specific reference.

Some references are:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

My analogy would be to say that alternate data streams are this (software) generation's "hidden" files.

Comment: (I have not finished reading all the content in the links) So this concept is called a data stream. Does it also contain the word "Stream" somewhere too? this kind of seems to me like if I search "File" I should get everything returned but I don't.